# Uploading file and posting text input values in one click?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-web-api, forms

I'm trying build an Asp.net web api for posting files. I found the following example in 
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AngularJS-with-Web-API-22f62a6e

The Web API method is:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/photo")]
public class PhotoController : ApiController
{
    private IPhotoManager photoManager;

    public PhotoController()
        : this(new LocalPhotoManager(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + @"\Album"))
    {            
    }

    public PhotoController(IPhotoManager photoManager)
    {
        this.photoManager = photoManager;
    }

    // GET: api/Photo
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
    {
        var results = await photoManager.Get();
        return Ok(new { photos = results });
    }

    // POST: api/Photo
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
    {
        // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
        if(!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
        {
            return BadRequest("Unsupported media type");
        }

        try
        {
            var photos = await photoManager.Add(Request);
            return Ok(new { Message = "Photos uploaded ok", Photos = photos });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.GetBaseException().Message);
        }

    }
```

And the file uploader html code: (I added a text input `<input type="text" id="test" value="testit" />` for test.

```
<form name="newPhotosForm" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" ng-disabled="appStatus.busy || photoManagerStatus.uploading">
    <div class="form-group" ng-hide="hasFiles">
        <label for="newPhotos">select and upload new photos</label>
        <input type="file" id="newPhotos" class="uploadFile" accept="image/*" eg-files="photos" has-files="hasFiles" multiple>
        <input type="text" id="test" value="testit" /> <!--- Added a text input for test -->
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-show="hasFiles && !photoManagerStatus.uploading">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li><strong>files:</strong></li>
            <li ng-repeat="photo in photos"> {{photo.name}}</li>
        </ul>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" eg-upload="upload(photos)" value="upload">
        <input class="btn btn-warning" type="reset" value="cancel" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-show="photoManagerStatus.uploading">
        <p class="help-block">uploading</p>
    </div>
</form>
```

The JS `upload` function:

```
function upload(photos)
{
    service.status.uploading = true;
    appInfo.setInfo({ busy: true, message: "uploading photos" });            

    var formData = new FormData();

    angular.forEach(photos, function (photo) {
        formData.append(photo.name, photo);
    });

    return photoManagerClient.save(formData)
                                .$promise
                                .then(function (result) {
                                    if (result && result.photos) {
                                        result.photos.forEach(function (photo) {
                                            if (!photoExists(photo.name)) {
                                                service.photos.push(photo);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }

                                    appInfo.setInfo({message: "photos uploaded successfully"});

                                    return result.$promise;
                                },
                                function (result) {
                                    appInfo.setInfo({message: "something went wrong: " + result.data.message});
                                    return $q.reject(result);
                                })
                                ['finally'](
                                function () {
                                    appInfo.setInfo({ busy: false });                                            
                                    service.status.uploading = false;
                                });
}
```

However, it seems the value of the added input `test` cannot be passed to the Web API code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add custom DTO/POCO class, set the values and then pass it as parameter to your post method. Since file is not a simple type default MediaTypeFormatter of webAPI won't work so you need to build your custom MediaTypeFormatter.

Sample POCO class

```
Public Class Attachment
{
    public string Input {get;set;}
    public byte[] Content{get;set;}
}
```

Custom Media formatter as below

```
public class CustomFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public CustomFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(Attachment);
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public async override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        var provider = await content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();

        var modelContent = provider.Contents
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "application/json"); 

        var attachment = await modelContent.ReadAsAsync<Attachment>();

        var fileContents = provider.Contents
            .Where(c => c.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "image/jpeg").FirstOrDefault(); // or whatever is the type of file to upload

        attachment.Content = await fileContents.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        return attachment;

    }
}
```

Register the custom media formatter:

```
private void ConfigureWebApi(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    //other code here
    config.Formatters.Add(new CustomFormatter());
}
```

Pass the POCO to your Web-API Controller

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Attachment attachment)
{
```

I haven't tested this in Visual Studio, but this is the approach you need to follow

More information here: 
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters

And a sample here 
http://blog.marcinbudny.com/2014/02/sending-binary-data-along-with-rest-api.html#.V5MDDzV7qYg